How to change the default color of Button in Jetpack Compose
Is there a way in Jetpack Compose to automatically apply the primary color defined in the theme to the background of Button composables without specifying the background color every time I use a button, just like we do in XML?
In XML, when we update the primary color, the button's background color also updates automatically. The Button composable did not change its background color when I updated the primary color in MaterialTheme. Instead, it kept using the default color, and I had to manually set the background color for each button.
In my Theme.kt file:
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = PrimaryGreen,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40

I have the color defined in my Color. kt file as:
val PrimaryGreen = Color(0xFF4DC800)

Before changing color, it was like this:
Code Snippet
I'm using these color schemes in my app main theme:
@Composable
fun PracticeTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
val colorScheme = when {
    dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
    }

    darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
    else -> LightColorScheme
}

MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
)

}

Can you share the code you have for the button you are using? You can use something like this: color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary

You can use something like this `val buttonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
)
Button(
onClick = { /* Button click action */ },
colors = buttonColors,`

@BobSmith Then I have to add background color, everytime i have to use a button, that's what i said in the post.

You can create a custom PrimaryButton composable that inherits the primary color and reduces boilerplate code. If you need it as answer I can post.

@BobSmith Help me with that BoilerPlate Code.

@M.Riyan ask it as different question and share me your post link.

@BobSmith I have done that, i create a custom component. but this is the roundabout way. If someone knows how to tackle it accurately, it would be appreciated.

You can do it using three ways as mentioned below :

Using contentColor based on theme
Using Surface with contentColor
Custom Button with Theming Option


@MalaikaKhan, could you please add a snippet showing where you are setting the color scheme? Additionally, can you clarify which color the button defaults to when the button color isn't explicitly specified?

@AdnanHabib i have added my theme.kt file before changing the primary color

You have DarkColorScheme and LightColorScheme in your Theme.kt file but where are you using these schemes?

@AdnanHabib I'm using these themes in my main theme of app

Since you have enabled dynamicColor, your app will not follow the specified color scheme when tested on Android 12 or higher.

@AdnanHabib yes, I'm testing on Android 10

Are you using Button composable from material or material3 library?

@AdnanHabib Jetpack Compose uses material3 library by default. I think you don't have the answer.

@MalaikaKhan, we are all here to help each other. Regarding the design system, we can use both Material and Material3 in Jetpack Compose. Since you haven't included the Button code, I tried both Material and Material3 buttons and found that the Material Button was not using the theme colors by default, which could be a potential cause of the issue.
Please consider editing your question to include a minimal reproducible example. This will allow others to help you more effectively without needing to ask additional questions.

@AdnanHabib please post your answer with all the details and code, so we could marked it correct.

The key here is to not use a dynamic color scheme. A dynamic color scheme is derived from the user's wallpaper, as described here. What you're going for here is to use a predetermined color scheme, regardless of whether the user is on Android 12 or later.
If you want to avoid using dynamic colors in certain parts of your app but reserve the ability to do so in other parts, you can pass false into your PracticeTheme() function in those places where you want to use your explicitly determined color scheme. For example, if you want to avoid using dynamic colors in a specific Activity, you might have code like this:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MenuLightTheme(dynamicColor = false) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

Or, if you don't want any part of your app to ever use dynamic colors, you can remove the dynamicColor parameter from your PracticeTheme() function entirely, in which case you would have something like this:
@Composable
fun PracticeTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}

